# How can I prevent YouTube comments from showing as my video description in Google Search results?

Tags: youtube, google-search

I was Googling my own site and saw this in the search results:

> [image: search results]

I was rather annoyed to see that somebody's comment was being used for the video description, instead of the actual description ("Quick runthrough of what we have so far."):

> [image: comment]

How can I fix this problem? It's rather annoying and makes it look as though I wrote that comment as the description.

Comment: Hypothesis: Try editing the video description, making it longer and more informative, explaining the context and all. Also try adding keywords if you haven't already. Hopefully this will trigger the Google search engine to update its snippet for the video, and it'll be useful to viewers in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SEO works in mysterious ways when it comes to video descriptions on YouTube.

I can say this, from my own experience - It's best to write a very detailed and uber-targeted description **containing links to authority sites** to have google index your video with your description.

Also, try using the "*fetch and render*" option on the **[Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)**. You can try and change the description by submitting a page from your own blog, where the video appears as part of an article on the same subject.

This might trigger a change in the bot's crawl behaviour, resulting in your video being indexed with your own content instead of the comments.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the long-delayed answer-accept. Now it shows something entirely unrelated by TechRax. I'll see if I can get that fixed up.

Comment: Awesome. Let me know if you find out exactly what caused this!